# ModuleNotFoundError and circular import

Tags: python, import, modulenotfounderror

I can't manage to import some functions in the files. Here is the structure

```
.
├── main.py
├── src
│   ├── mypandas.py
│   ├── labelling.py
```

Labelling uses class from mypandas and mypandas uses functions from labelling.

Labelling imports mypandas as

```
import mypandas as myp
```

mypandas imports labelling as

```
import labelling as l
```

In main, I import both as

```
import src.labelling as sl
import src.mypandas as sp
```

Which gives me an error,: module not

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 7
      5 import src.webscraping as sw
      6 import src.viz as sv
----> 7 import src.mypandas as sp
      9 import sqlite3
     10 import pandas as pd 

File ~/Desktop/code/Instagram_bot_classification/src/mypandas.py:5
      1 def foo (): 
      2     print('oui')
----> 5 import labelling
      6 import pandas as pd
      7 import plotly.express as px

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'labelling'
```

How can I change the folder structure or code to not get an error but still to what I want?

Comment: Try import .labelling in mypandas.py

Comment: For starters, "*Labelling uses class from mypandas and mypandas uses functions from labelling*" is not a good design, as it will immediately lead to circular imports (which is not what your error is, BTW).

Comment: Usually you don't import `src` explicitly.

Comment: @Marc: Did you look at [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: @MattDMo, how should I design it instead? merge both files and just import from one?

Comment: That's probably the easiest way to go. Make a `utils.py` and put common, shared stuff in there. If there's still significant functionality to be coded, keep `mypandas.py` and/or `labelling.py`, and have both `import .utils`. If it makes sense to put *everything* together, just `import src.utils` in `main.py`, then adjust your other references to `sl` and `sp` accordingly.